# Path Integral in QM - Fourier Transform with respect to a Function?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-distributions, fourier-transform, quantum-mechanics, characteristic-functions

Consider the Fourier transform of a multivariable probability density function $Pr(\{x_n\})$, i.e. its characteristic function:

$\int Pr(\{x_n\})e^{-i2\pi\sum\limits_{n}f_nx_n}\prod\limits_{n}{dx_n}$,

which can be considered a Fourier transform with respect to a vector variable $\vec{x}$.

Now suppose instead, we consider a probability density function defined over the space of all functions of t over the region from t = 0 to t = t, $Pr[x(t)]$. We can define a path integral as follows:

$\int Pr[x(t)]e^{-i2\pi\int\limits_{0}^tL(x,\dot{x})dt}D[x(t)]$.

If $Pr[x(t)]$ is constant across all functions, then the integral is just the usual Feynman path integral. In analogy to the above, would it be possible to consider this a Fourier transform with respect to a function, i.e. the characteristic function of $Pr[x(t)]$?

Comment: In your first equation there is a vector $\vec{f}$ which is independent of the vector $\vec{x}$ being integrated. In your second equation is there a second function independent of the function $x(t)$ being integrated over?

Comment: In the second equation, the integral is over  $L(x,\dot{x})$ where $\dot{x}$ is the time derivative of $x(t)$. x is short-hand for $x(t)$.

Comment: Which seems to only depend on the function $x(t)$ being integrated over, not any other function. If you want something analogous to a Fourier transform, you need to replace $\int L$ with something akin to an inner product between $x(t)$ and $f(t)$, no?

Comment: Yes, I agree. Would it be possible in general to write $L(x,\dot{x})$ as a product of some generalized function with x(t)? I feel like this should be possible given that the derivative of any function can be found by taking a dot product with the Dirac delta function's derivative.

Comment: Then again, f(t) would need to be a monotonically increasing *actual* function. I'll file the answer to my question under "no", with some caveats. I have some thoughts and intend to write up an answer to my own question later unless another good answer comes around.

Answer (score 1):

So, the main problem here is a QM amplitude (as one derives from the path integral) is a *complex number*, while a Fourier transform outputs a *function*. But nonetheless, let's see what analogy can be drawn:

We'll assume without loss of generality that we're working with one particle. So, in classical mechanics, the Lagrangian, $L(x,\dot{x})$ may be related to the Hamiltonian via Legendre transform, i.e. $L(x,\dot{x}) = p\dot{x} - H(x,p)$, where p is the momentum and is now considered to be independent of x.

Substituting into the formula for the path integral I provided in the OP, we get:

$\int Pr[x(t)]e^{-i2\pi\int\limits_{0}^t(p\dot{x} - H)dt}D[x(t)]$,

which may be rewritten as:

$\int Pr[x(t)]e^{-i2\pi\int\limits_{0}^tpdx - Hdt}D[x(t)]$.

If p and H were considered to be totally independent variables of x(t), then yes, you could consider something like this as a characteristic function on path space. The problem is, they both vary along each path, and the end result of the integral is a complex number. So the answer to the question as written is "no".

Perhaps someone else has additional insight that I don't?

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to view the path integral formalism as a functional Fourier transform of a functional differential formalism.
[Manoukian, 2020](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-51081-7_24). So the answer to your question is still "no" but there is a thread you can follow that gives you the essential idea you were after. (Apologies that article is behind a pay-wall, I cannot locate a similar paper on the arXiv.)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).